# create own kafkaproducer

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am learning Kafka and I was trying to use python to write own producer.

I was trying to play with simple loop, however I got assertion error:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:7092'])
for x in range (10):
    topic = "kafkatopic"
    producer.send(topic=topic,value="text")
    x=x+1
```

Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can test this code and I useing [Kafka Python client](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) package:

`producer.py` :

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=['XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092'],
)
for x in range (10):
    producer.send('kafkatopic', b'this is a test')
    producer.flush()

print('finish')
```

`consumer.py`

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('kafkatopic',
                     bootstrap_servers=['XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092'],
                     auto_offset_reset= 'smallest')
for message in consumer:
    print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,message.offset, message.key,message.value))
```

Comment: Quick question, what does the b in producer.send mean? why I can not directly say 'this is test'?

Comment: because you must convert a `string` to `bytes` before sending it to Kafka